# Asymptotics of perturbations of polynomial systems

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, polynomials

Disclaimer: the following question is taken from math.SE. It relates to perturbation theory, and I'm interested in references (if any) that relate to the following problem:

Suppose we are given a system of equations $f_1, \cdots, f_n$ in $n$ real variables $x_1, \cdots, x_n$ parameterised by $\delta, \epsilon$ sufficiently small and positive, and we wish to solve $$\{f_{i, \delta, \epsilon}(x_1, \cdots, x_n) = 0\mid 1 \leq i \leq n\}$$ asymptotically, but in $\delta$ for fixed $\epsilon$. (So the coefficients of the expansion should be functions of $\epsilon$.) Suppose $f_{i, \delta, \epsilon}$ is polynomial in $x_1, \cdots, x_n, \delta$ and with coefficients that are analytic functions of $\epsilon$. (In general, $\epsilon$ could also be multivariate.)

The usual way to approach this is to find a solution for $x_1, \cdots, x_n$ in terms of $\delta, \epsilon$, then expand them as $\delta \rightarrow 0^+$. However, the coefficients could be complicated functions of $\epsilon$, and solving the system in full generality might be quite difficult. If we expand the coefficients first in terms of $\epsilon \rightarrow 0^+$, then the resulting system $\smash{\{\tilde{f}_{i,\delta,\epsilon}\}}$ might be more tractable. If we solve this system first, finding solutions $\tilde{x}_1, \cdots, \tilde{x}_n$, then expand as $\delta \rightarrow 0^+$, what can we say about the approximate solutions and the true solutions $x_1, \cdots, x_n$? Better yet, are there any sufficient conditions for which the approximate solutions are close to the true solutions, for $\delta, \epsilon$ sufficiently small?

In particular, if we consider the single equation $x^2 - 2\cos(\epsilon)x + 1 = 0$, this has no solution for any $\epsilon > 0$, but a linear approximation to $\cos\epsilon$ implies a double root at $x = 1$, whereas a quadratic approximation implies no solution. Is there an $N > 0$ sufficiently large depending on presumably the coefficients and the polynomials $f_i$, for which an expansion of the coefficients up to order $\mathcal{O}(\epsilon^{N+1})$ implies the approximate system is close to the original system?

EDIT: original post [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3376216/solving-a-system-of-equations-asymptotically).

Comment: Link to the math.se post?

Comment: It's been added

Comment: Would this even work for linear systems? Suppose for instance that $f(\epsilon )$ and $g(\epsilon )$ are distinct functions such that the Taylor polynomials agree up to some arbitrary order. The system $x-y=f(\epsilon )$ and $x-y=g(\epsilon )$ is inconsistent, but we have no effective bound on how far to Taylor expand in order to certify this fact.

Comment: $N$ is permitted to depend on the coefficients and the polynomials, so if $f, g$ are fixed then unless $f = g$ then they will agree up order, say, $n$, in which case an expansion up to order $N = n+1$ is enough.